# How to retrieve MS Office 2013 Home Product Key from the program files?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, microsoft-office, product-key

I had bought a MS Office 2013 Home Edition in 2014 and lost it's original CD which had the Product Key after some time. Recently I decided to upgrade my laptop and got the Original HDD replaced with a new SSD and reinstalled all the programs. Now I face this dilemma as I no longer have access to the Product Key nor did I connect it to a Microsoft Account so the only files I have left are the files on the original HDD which I have with the help of some external apparatus converted to an external HDD. These files are the program files.

Is there some way to find the product key from the program files which I have in the original C Drive of my HDD?

Comment: Call Microsoft Support and give them your name, address, phone and email address. They may be able to find your order details. Recover Keys app might work but since the old drive does not appear to be running, it may not.

Comment: Recover keys (https://recover-keys.com/) will scan another computer / drive and might work. Try it and see.

Comment: Were you able to recover the key?

Comment: @John The program's website had a not that only last 5 digits are recoverable by this process i haven't contacted microsoft yet i'll do that in some time

Comment: Is there any update? I find an [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-product-keys-with-office-12a5763a-d45c-4685-8c95-a44500213759#bkmk_lostkey), it said "If you damaged your product key, but have **a valid proof of purchase**, Microsoft support **may be** able to replace your product key or provide other options. [Contact Microsoft support](https://support.microsoft.com/contactus/) for assistance."

Comment: I have talked to a family friend who did the process initially i have some exams right now but after that he said he'll try to reconnect the HDD and then retrieve the original key so hoping for that. I doubt this method will work as I saw somewhere that they demanded that it must have been purchased from a Microsoft Store online or offline while mine wasn't one (not sure though). I'll give this a try as well once I am free after the exams. Thanks for sharing @Emily